# Java некорректно работает переопределение toString

Tags: java

Переопределяю toString для вывода конкретных значений, а на месте значений выводится null (сами значения я для проверки выводил внутри метода,где они используются, все выводится корректно, в чем может быть проблема?

class Contact

```
package ru.skillbench.tasks.text;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.Period;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ContactCardImpl implements ContactCard {
private String FN;
private String ORG;
private String GENDER;
private Date BDAY;
private String TEL;


@Override
public ContactCard getInstance(Scanner scanner) throws ParseException {
    ContactCard card = new ContactCardImpl();
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();

        if (line.contains("FN:")) {
            FN = line.substring(3);
            System.out.println(FN);
        }
        if (line.contains("ORG:")) {
            ORG = line.substring(4);
            System.out.println(ORG);
        }
        if (line.contains("GENDER:")) {
             GENDER = line.substring(7);
            System.out.println(GENDER);
        }
        if (line.contains("BDAY:")) {
            BDAY = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(line.substring(5));
            System.out.println(BDAY);
        }
        if (line.contains("TEL;")) {
            TEL = line.substring(34);
            System.out.println(TEL);
        }

    }
    scanner.close();


    return card;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Карта человека{" +
            "Полное Имя=" + FN +
            ", Организаация=" + ORG +
            ", Пол=" + GENDER +
            ", Дата рождения=" +BDAY +
            ", Телефон(ы)=" +TEL +
            "}";
}
}
```

Вот, что получаю при выводе:

```
Forrest Gump
Bubba Gump Shrimp Co.
Tue Jun 06 00:00:00 MSK 1944
+1-111-555-1212
+1-404-555-1212
Карта человека{Полное Имя=null, Организаация=null, Пол=null, Дата рождения=null, Телефон(ы)=null}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Скорее  всего, `getInstance` должен быть `static`. Тогда вы увидите проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    ContactCardImpl card = new ContactCardImpl();
    if (line.contains("FN:")) {
        card.FN = line.substring(3);
        ^^^^^
        System.out.println(card.FN);
    }
```

и так далее.

Comment: просто с card.FN не сработало, выдает ошибку. Но сработало вот так: ((ContactCardImpl) card).FN = line.substring(3); Можете пожалуйста объяснить что это, а то нагуглить не выходит. На какое явное преобразование типов похоже, но какую роль это играть здесь?

Comment: @volnistii Да, это я ошибся. У типа `ContactCard` нет полей. Они появляются только у `ContactCardImpl`. Вот и надо объявить переменную `card` как `ContactCardImpl`.

Comment: Ага, понял. Разрешите еще один небольшой вопрос. Почему такая реализация возможна, если при реализации метода я явно указываю тип возвращаемого объекта(public ContactCard getInstance(Scanner scanner)). А если реализовать так, как сказали вы, то получается, что будет возвращаться объекта типа ContactCardImpl. И это работает=)

Comment: @volnistii Потому что любой объект типа `ContactCardImpl` одновременно является и `ContactCard`.

Comment: Понял, а тогда в каких случаях стоит делать тип объекта ContactCardImpl, а когда ContactCard=)

Comment: @volnistii Вот в данном случае, внутри функции Вам нужен доступ к полям `ContactCardImpl`. Значит тип `card` должен быть `ContactCardImpl`. Общее правило - типы надо выбирать настолько менее конкретные типы, насколько это возможно.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо=)Жаль нельзя две галочки поставить)))

Answer (score 1):

Вы же хотите вернуть `card`, так почему вы заполняете поля текущего класса а не нового объекта `ContactCard card = new ContactCardImpl()`?